# Qlik Sense count if Null

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I would like to count the number of employees as of today.
The condition should be
Join Day <= Today <= Resign Date OR Resign Date is blank.
My formula is as below, how can I add the condition that Resign Date is blank?

> Count({$<[Join Date]={"<=$(=Today())"}, [Resign
> Date]={">=$(=Today())"}>}distinct[Employee Code])

Answer (score 3):

Easier will be not to deal with `null` in the set analysis :)

If you can create a new field in the script for each employee - `ResignedStatus` (for example):

```
...
if( isNull([Resign Date]), 'not resigned', 'resigned') as ResignedStatus,
...
```

After we have this field then the expression to get the count of not resigned users is simple:

```
count( {< ResignedStatus= {'not resigned'} >} distinct [Employee Code] )
```

And the overall expression will be:

```
Count({$<[Join Date]={"<=$(=Today())"}, [Resign Date]={">=$(=Today())"}>}distinct[Employee Code]) 

+ 

count( {< ResignedStatus= {'not resigned'} >} distinct [Employee Code] )
```